# Send push notifications from server

Tags: c++, ios, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I am currently writing a client-server game for the iOS platform, and I wish to push notifications to specific users once it's their turn to make a move. I have had a look at Parse.com and their API, but I haven't completely decided how to deal with push notifications just yet, so I'm open for other solutions.

I am wondering how I can push notifications to specific users using the server program. The server currently stores usernames, PW-hash values and device tokens in its database of users, but I am not sure if using the device token is what I need to push the notifications. The server is written in C++, and communicates with a MySQL database.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend going with Parse.  They make so many things really easy and the free plan can handle a lot before you have to start paying.

I use parse and love it!

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to send pushes from the server software (C++) using Parse?

Comment: You can send pushes through Parse from another server using their REST API.  https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/REST